# I am not able to differentiate two objects while importing excel sheet in PHP

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to import an excel sheet into database using PHP. When I read sheet I get data in different format.When only one sheet is inserted I get data in a single array and when I insert two or more sheets I get multiple array in object format in both the cases.So I am not able to differentiate single array and multiple array and not able to insert values in database.

```
$path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
                {})->get();
```

here for single sheet in $data I get

`[ { "id":1,"name":"Nilima" } ]` format and for multiple sheets I get
`[ [ {  "id":1,"name":"Nilima" } ], [ ], [ ] ]`. But type of both response is object.

Can anyone please help me to solve this.I am badly stucked in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` the result you got.

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
```

then write a function to check the index of arrays to find format.

Example:

```
function is_multi_sheet_arr($arr){
    if(isset($arr[0][0])){
       return true;
    } else if(isset($arr[0])){
       return false;
    }
}
```

get arr element based on that.

Happy coding

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark it as answer so this will help other people also. Happy coding